# Should I edit or delete when original question had wrong code?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question, which didn't get any response for a day or two.

Then I realised I'd pasted the wrong code into it (I asked about lists, when I'd used a variable instead in the pasted code).

I've been using a small simple script to learn, so I have several versions of it implementing different solutions to problems.

So since it's already been up a little while, do I delete it, or edit it?

Comment: Since it didn't get any response, delete it and post a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question has no answers you can either delete and repost or edit. It makes no real difference as both the new question or the edited question will appear (if only briefly!) on the home page. On balance, editing is probably the better option as deleted questions can count against you when the system calculates whether you've hit the low quality question block or not.

If the question has been answered, then you are in trickier territory. Editing will more than likely invalidate the existing answers and that's not nice. In this case. A single answer with a zero score won't prevent you from deleting the question and reposting. Multiple answers, or an answer with a positive score will prevent you from deleting so the best thing here is to just repost a new question.

If you can, flag or vote to close the question so others don't waste time answering it.