# Should I edit my existing question or ask a new one if adding new data invalidates old data?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45575435/mediawiki-login-cancelled-to-prevent-session-hijacking) two weeks ago, and shortly after a user requested more information in the comments, which I edited into the question. Since then, I've pursued a solution on my own and though I still haven't found one, I have found more information which might be helpful.

However, my problem involves a session being stored improperly. Therefore, to troubleshoot, people need to look at whether or not certain data is the same in different places (for example, if a token is the same in my log and response header).

So if I add this new data the old data becomes useless unless I update it, but in searching for a solution I have made changes to my installation from the original question. Since I don't know what's wrong, I don't know if this means I'll change any fundamental details of the question.

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. I can go ahead and update my question with a completely fresh set of data, but I'm afraid this may end up changing my question without me realizing or understanding.
2. I can create a new question with the fresh set of data, but I also run a pretty good risk of just posting an identical question. The behavior I'm getting from my new installation seems the same to me, so there's a good chance the answer to both questions would be the same.

All other questions I've found regarding the "start a new question or edit old question" topic seem to match cases I don't fall into, and I'm not sure how to handle this case. Also, if there's another option from my 2, please let me know.

NOTE: I don't think this is a duplicate of *[Should I edit or delete when original question had wrong code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348859/should-i-edit-or-delete-when-original-question-had-wrong-code)*, as the original question had no wrong data on its own. Rather, the issue is adding new data invalidates the old data.

Comment: If editing the question invalidates existing answers then it shouldn't be edited. At least that's how I think it should work. Considering point 2 you mention that there is a good chance the answer to both questions would be the same so such an edit wouldn't invalidate the current answer would it not? If not then I'd make the edit and maybe leave a comment on the answer to let them know about the edit so they can adapt if needed.

Comment: One point of concern would be if the original question had any value at all given the inaccurate data. If it was effectively answered, I would think it should remain unedited. But if the question itself would only confuse or worse, inaccurately direct another user with the inaccuracies, perhaps a vote to delete. On the other hand, as I stated, if the answer is effective in solving the post and that information could feasibly help another, leave it and add an edit and perhaps link to the new question with the new parameter data.

Answer (score 3):

The question you should ask yourself is:

## Do editing the silly mistake I did, makes clearer what the problem is?

Absolutely yes. We have no problem invalidating existing answers if the question has irrelevant or misleading information that muddles the problem. That's the principle behind asking a MCVE. If by providing a *better* MCVE you invalidate answers, good riddance. The answerers could have sussed out the MCVE in the comments before hand.